# let user create and sign erc20 transactions but i pay the fees?

Tags: transactions, gas, dapp-development, fees, meta-transactions

I try to build an app where users can send and receive ERC20 tokens.

I want the transactions for my user to be feeless.

So is it possible for a user to create and sign the transactions,
my system collects these transactions and submit them to the network and pays their Ethereum fees?

Answer (score 2):

Yes! This pattern of transactions is called metatransactions.

As you described, your user would *sign* the transaction, but you would send the transaction to the network via a metatransaction.

There are a number of different ways to implement it. The [Gas Station Network (GSN) by OpenZeppelin](https://gsn.openzeppelin.com/) provides this as a service and is worth considering for your use.

Comment: this GSN is quite abstracted and multi-purpose.i really need the minimum.

e.g.
the user creates and signs a transaction
gives this transaction to me
i broadcast the tx and pay the gas

how would i go about this with minimum tools?